# Vertical and Horizontal alignment using mintage for a quad chart

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, minipage

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{QuadChart}
        
        \fbox{  \begin{minipage}[b][0.3\textheight][t]{0.4\textwidth}
                    \textbf{Objective:}
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item Item 1 
                    \end{itemize}
                \end{minipage}  }

        \hfill 
        \fbox{  \begin{minipage}[b][0.3\textheight][t]{0.4\textwidth}
                    \textbf{Significance:}
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item Item 2
                    \end{itemize}
                \end{minipage}  }

        \fbox{  \begin{minipage}[b][0.3\textheight][t]{0.4\textwidth}
                    \textbf{Approach:}
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item Item 3 
                    \end{itemize}
                \end{minipage}  }

        \fbox{  \begin{minipage}[b][0.3\textheight][t]{0.4\textwidth}
                    \textbf{Result:}
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item Item 4 
                    \end{itemize}
                \end{minipage}  }
                
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not really specify the desired alignment of the boxes, the following is based on a guess:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{QuadChart}
        \begin{columns}
          \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \fbox{  \begin{minipage}[b][0.3\textheight][t]{0.8\textwidth}
                      \textbf{Objective:}
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item Item 1 
                      \end{itemize}
                  \end{minipage}  }
                  
            \bigskip
        
            \fbox{  \begin{minipage}[b][0.3\textheight][t]{0.8\textwidth}
                      \textbf{Approach:}
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item Item 3
                      \end{itemize}
                  \end{minipage}  }
          \end{column}
          \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \fbox{  \begin{minipage}[b][0.3\textheight][t]{0.8\textwidth}
                      \textbf{Significance}
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item Item 2 
                      \end{itemize}
                  \end{minipage}  }
                  
            \bigskip

            \fbox{  \begin{minipage}[b][0.3\textheight][t]{0.8\textwidth}
                    \textbf{Result:}
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item Item 4 
                      \end{itemize}
                  \end{minipage}  }
           \end{column}
          \end{columns} 
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```